# Can't figure how to set two variables in a single IF statement

Tags: scheme, gimp, script-fu

I'm trying to write my first Gimp script, but I can't seem to get it set two variables in a single IF statement :

```
(if
  (< a b)
  ((set! a 100)(set! b 200))
  ((set! a 200)(set! b 100))
)
```

I get an illegal function error.  It works if I set a single variable.  How should I write it to work with two (or more) ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot `begin`:

```
(if
  (< a b)
  (begin (set! a 100) (set! b 200))
  (begin (set! a 200) (set! b 100))
)
```

`begin` basically just executes all of its arguments.